# if $z=(1+i\sqrt{3})^n$ there are real numbers $A$ and $B$ so that $z$ equals...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

if $z=(1+i\sqrt{3})^n$ where $n$ is a positive integer, there are real numbers $A$ and $B$ so that $z$ equals... (and here are the alternatives from the exam)

(a) $A+B\sqrt{3}$

(b) $A+Bi\sqrt{3}$

(c) $A\sqrt{3}+Bi$

(d) none of the above

this is way too strange and unknown territory for me. I can't even start to guess how to proceed and solve this. If asking these types of questions is going to be a problem please let me know and I'll adapt accordingly.

Comment: Calculate $(1+i\sqrt{3})^2$ ... $(1+i\sqrt{3})^3$ ... etc ...

Comment: I'm guessing $A$ and $B$ are not real numbers, but integers. Otherwise both (b) and (c) are correct.

Comment: When the imaginary part is exponentiated to an even power, it is a real integer. When it is exponentiated to an odd number, it is imaginary and irrational. With this in mind, it’s easy to see that the answer is b

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

In the first place, notice that
\begin{align*}
1 + i\sqrt{3} = 2\left(\frac{1}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right) = 2\left[\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\right]
\end{align*}

Then you may apply the De Moivre's theorem
\begin{align*}
[\rho(\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta))]^{n} = \rho^{n}(\cos(n\theta) + i\sin(n\theta))
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use [De Moivre's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula) to come up with an answer.

Comment: aha okay thanks...I'll check it out

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite the expressing as $f(x)=(1+x)^n = a_0+a_1x+...a_nx^n$ and substitue x by $i\sqrt{3}$ so that $x^2=-3$. Now it is easy to show that $f(x)=A+Bx$